# How to make number to round down to divisible by 100 in php?

Tags: php, numbers

I just want to round down the number to divisible by 100 i.e if number = 299 , 240 i want to output 200.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$a = 240; 

$b = 260; 

echo (floor($a / 100))*100;

echo "<br>";

echo (floor($b / 100))*100;
```

So, (floor( $a / 100 ))*100 is the trick for you here. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you Bashir for your contributions but my requirements are different i have to round down the figure that may divisible by 100 lets support we have 299 i want to round down it 200 your answer will make it 300 so no need to do all that we can do simple round() for that

Comment: Ok. Then Just use the floor() function instead of round(). Hopefully that will fulfill your requirements

Comment: Yes thats why i used that  Thank you  @Muhammad for your support

Comment: My pleasure. Kindly mark it as approved if that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using division will give you floating point number, which will again need round function to convert it into integer. I would suggest you to use mod operation

eg.

```
$num1 = 278;
$num2 = 100;  // or it could be 10,100,1000

$result = $num1 - ($num1 % $num2);
//e.g. 200 = 278 - (278%100)
```

Comment: @kantsverma can you tell where its going wrong and what are your requirements..?

Comment: yes just tested working fine. Thank you to make it more short.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that can help you to round down the number to nearest

```
    $number = 299;
    echo '<br/>Result '.floor($number / 100) * 100;
```

Similarly if you want to round down to any other figure like 10 then follow below code

```
$number = 90;
    echo '<br/>Result '.floor($number / 10) * 10;
```